# How can I add list value to particular column

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Color': ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'black'], \
        'Product ID': [1, 2, 3, 4], \
        'Product Name': ['t-shirt', 't-shirt', 'skirt', 'skirt']})
        'Price': [4, 5, 6, 5]
print(df1)
```

This is the whole code. and I want to add `[-2, -1, 1, 2]` to the `column['price']`
to make the `column['price'] = [2, 4, 7, 7]`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try via `.loc` accessor:

```
df1['Price']=df1['Price']+[-2, -1, 1, 2]
#OR
df1.loc[:,'Price']=df1.loc[:,'Price']+[-2, -1, 1, 2]
```

OR

Try via `pd.Series()`:

```
df1['Price']=df1['Price']+pd.Series([-2, -1, 1, 2])
```

OR

via `.values` attribute:

```
df1['Price']=df1['Price'].values+[-2, -1, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
df1['Price'] = df1.Price + [-2, -1, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways you can do this with pandas. One way is to use the .assign method on the pandas dataframe like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Color': ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'black'], 
        'Product ID': [1, 2, 3, 4], 
        'Product Name': ['t-shirt', 't-shirt', 'skirt', 'skirt'],
        'Price': [4, 5, 6, 5]})
print(df1)

df1 = df1.assign(Price = df1.Price + np.array([-2,-1,1,2]))
print(df1)
```

Other syntax is available with the .assign() method.